# How to prevent slider from turning "bad" near the edge

Tags: objective-c, uislider, xcode4.5

I supplied slider graphic for my slider.

This is the result:
[image]

Then on the right
[image]

So you see, the edge become a "box" rather than rounded. What I really want is something that's closer with what apple provide. This is the code I used to switch back and forth between using custom slider image and nil:

```
- (IBAction)groupPinButton:(id)sender {
    self.groupPinButton.selected = ! self.groupPinButton.selected;
    UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"minimum_slider.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets2:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"maximum_slider.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets2:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 5)];
    if (self.groupPinButton.selected)
    {


        [self.distanceSlider setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.distanceSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{

        [self.distanceSlider setMaximumTrackImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.distanceSlider setMinimumTrackImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

If I set the maximumTrackImage as nil, this is the screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Which looks  lot nicer. But I want to customize.

The pictures that I use for minimum_slider.png and maximum_slider.png is the following:

[image]
[image]

and you can get there at

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n30aw.png

and

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF9SQ.png

Note the other edge is fine though. So when slider is anywhere except the maximum and minimum things work fine. If the slider is at maximum then the far right corner is messed up. The far left corner is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! The same problem I was having. As you get to the end of the program, and the slider is at maximum, the entire track image is now the left side, the "minimum_slider.png" in your example. Thus there is no part of the "maximum_slider" image showing (which would have given you the rounded right edge), only the square right side of the "minimum_slider".

I suspect the answer is to give your two images rounded sides on both ends, and make the expandable parts (the edge insets) in the middle of the graphic.

I haven't done this yet, as I'm still confused as to the workings of UIEdgeInsets (I find the documentation terrible!) and the default track is sufficient for me now. So let us all know when you solve this.

Comment: I suspect that jrturton's suspicion of your suspicion is correct and will mark your answer once I proof his suspicious suspicions' suspicion.

Comment: While I wait in suspense as these suppositions are suspended, I would like to add: Adding my own images for the tracks and thumb I find problematic in two ways. One, the thumb doesn't seem to "catch" as well as the built-in thumb, and I often lose it after a brief movement. Two, as I hide and unhide it with a 1/2 second animation, I find the elements appear and disappear at different speeds. For an example, the thick red track and red button of Netflix's app. I don't like the way it shows and hides.